# bash script not working, cant spot any errors

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, case-statement

New user here, sorry if I am not posting correctly, but I have been staring at this code for hours and I cannot find out what is wrong with it, I made some code before that is very similar and that worked fine, please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash

export TERM=xterm
while true
do
    clear #Gets rid of previous output
    #displays main menu
    menu="Main menu: 
    showMan = Show the manual path.
    addMan = Add an item to the manual path.
    setMan = Set the manual path to '/man'.
    fileName = Enter filename.
    editFile = Edit file.
    headDisplay = How many lines to display of the head of the file?
    tailDisplay = How many lines to display of the tail of the file?
    listProcess = listing of processes
    userProcess = Processes run by user
    quit = Exit"
    echo -e "$menu";
    read -r option 
    #gets user choice
    clear
    case $option in
    "showMan") 
        echo $MANPATH 
        ;;

    "addMan")
        echo "Add an item"
        read -r item
        export MANPATH="$MANPATH:$item"
        ;;

    "setMan")
        export MANPATH="/man"
        ;;

    "fileName")
        echo "Enter filename:"
        read -r filename
        ;;

    "editFile")
        nano "$filename"
        ;;

    "headDisplay")
        echo "How many lines of code to display from top of the file?:"
        read -r numLines
        head -"$numLines" "$filename"
        ;;

    "tailDisplay")
        echo "How many lines of code to display from bottom of the file?:"
        read -r numLines
        tail -"$numLines" "$filename"
        ;;

    "listProcess")
        ps -ef
        ;;

    "userProcess")
        echo "Please enter username:"
        read -r username
        ps -u "$username" | sed 1d | wc -l
        ;;

    "quit")
        exit
        ;;

    *)
        echo "Invalid input."
        ;;
    esac

    #Asks user if they want to continue
    echo "Would you like to continue?  (Y/n)"
    read -r input
    if [ "$input" == "n" ]; then
        exit
    fi
done
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I am running it as an .sh file through the linux terminal and it doesnt actually tell me, it just says "bad interpreter: no such file or dictionary"

Comment: I have used other .SH files that work through the linux terminal though

Comment: I suggest to check your file with `cat -A file.sh` for special characters.

Comment: It says ^M$ after every line

Comment: Use `dos2unix file.sh` to fix this.

Comment: Thank you so so much Cyrus! that did the trick, I was staring at the code for hours, I can't believe that it was something so obscure, I never would have got that fixed without you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the she-bang at the very beginning of your script:

> #!/bin/bash

This instructs your current shell to use this interpreter/shell to execute the script. In your case it does not find the executable at */bin/bash*.

To fix the problem you should either change it to the location of your bash shell executable (you can find it with "which bash") or remove it to use the current shell.

I would prefer the path fix, because if you use bash specific commands and statements within the script it will break if you're using a different shell as default.

Comment: Tank you! That worked, however it is now throwing up another error: source_file.sh: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
source_file.sh: line 23: ` case $option in'

Comment: I copied the script from your post and pasted it into _vim_. Worked perfectly with Windows Ubuntu shell. Could be additionally an encoding issue. Did you remove the line, or fixed it with the correct path?

Comment: I removed the line, however I took Cyrus' advice and that fixed, thank you both so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Combined powers :)